# Adding TableViews to TabBarView & how to customise prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Im building my iphone application and this is how my storyboard looks right now.

[image]

First question: Adding another table view

My first two tab bar items are going to contain table views. Now as you can see i have my first table view connected and all, how would i do to get the empty view under Navigation Controller to be a a Table View. Would i need to add another Navigation controller? or how does it work cause i have never worked with tabbars/tableviews before.

Second question: Customize prototype cell

My first Table View can show the data that i inputed as you will see in the following picture. The first picture is how its currently being shown. How can i make a custom prototype cell that would look like the second picture?

**Please not that the cells will be very much alike each other in both of my table views. I will have an if statement where i will check a specific thing and if its true it will hide for example the image but all the other things would be the same so would i make a class for the cells?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For better solving your questions, You must first understand the purpose of Navigation Controller. Navigation Controller is there for you to push and pop between controllers, which is convenient when you have levels of data. It manages a stack of controllers. You don't always need a navigation controller to work with tableview. However, it's a common practice to put Navigation controller and TableView (with view controller or solely UITableViewController) together for easy showing levels of data.

   Basically, there are two ways to add a TableView. You can directly drag a table view onto your empty view controller or delete the empty VC, then drag a UITableViewController. Most importantly, select the whole VC and go to Editor (at the top) choose embed in a Navigation Controller.

   [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html) about navigation controller from Apple's document
2. Since you use storyboard, you can directly customize your tableViewcell in storyboard. You already have a prototype cell. You can now directly drag UIImage or Label on that. Most importantly, create a class subclassing UITableViewCell and connect objects in your tableViewCell as an IBOutlet so that you can control it. If you feel plain text explanation is not enough, I find a tutorial for you.

   You could refer to the [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702) section Prototype Cells.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes you will need a 2nd navigation controller for each tab.
Delete the UIViewController.
Drag a UITableViewController to the storyboard.
Embed the UITableViewController in a NavigationController.
Set a segue from the tab bar button to the new NavigationController.

2)
To fully set up the prototype cell you showed you will need to create a new class which subclasses UITableViewCell and then set IBOutlets for all the labels etc.